# @Valid not working on Spring when a incorrect request is sent

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make some validations for the DTOs in my spring application, when i send a request with blank or null values it should throw an exception, but its not doing it and it goes into the method. This is what i have

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@Validated
public class AccountController implements AccountAPI {
    private final AccountService accountService;
    @Override
    public AccountResponseDTO save(@RequestBody @Valid AccountCreateDTO account){
        return accountService.save(account);
    }

    @Override
    public AccountResponseDTO withdraw(@RequestBody @Valid TransactionAccountDTO transaction){
        return accountService.withdraw(transaction);
    }

    @Override
    public AccountResponseDTO deposit(@RequestBody @Valid TransactionAccountDTO transaction){
        return accountService.deposit(transaction);
    }

    @Override
    public TransferResponseDTO transfer(@RequestBody @Valid TransferRequestDTO transaction){
        return accountService.transfer(transaction);
    }

    @Override
    public AccountResponseDTO enableAccount(@PathVariable String accountNumber){
        return accountService.enableAccount(accountNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public AccountResponseDTO disableAccount(@PathVariable String accountNumber){
        return accountService.disableAccount(accountNumber);
    }
    @Override
    public void testPath(@Valid @RequestBody TransferRequestDTO transaction){
        System.out.println("It got here!");
    }


}
```

I'm using the testPath to "test" the validations to avoid problems with the service if the null or blank values go through.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class TransferRequestDTO {
    @NotBlank
    private String originAccountNumber;
    @NotBlank
    private String destinationAccountNumber;
    @Min(value = 0)
    private long amount;
}
```

This is the DTO and when I try something like this in postmant:

```
{
    "originAccountNumber":"",
    "destinationAccountNumber":"",
    "amount":null
}
```

It prints the line inside the method when it should throw an exception for the validations

I tried adding this to the pom (dependencies) but the problem its not gone

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also i tried adding @Validated in the controller class but nothing, am i missing something?

Comment: try a `Long` and add `@NotNull`, otherwise `null -> 0 -> valid` makes totally sense

Comment: (if you want to allow `0` and not allow `null` that's the way to go..)

Answer (score 0):

for long value you cannot set null because its not wrapper . for test that send 0 for amount .
for strings in your dto test @NotEmpty